# How can I form matrix lines programmaticaly based on an element list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, matrix, logic

I'm practicing some programming logic with a challenge that a friend shared with me. Here's the problem:

> Write a script that takes an integer n as the numbers of rows and columns of a matrix and take the element list of the matrix.
>
> ```
> Example: n=3 
>       matrix = [[11 2 4],
>                  [4 5 6],
>                  [10 8 -12] ]
> ```
>
> And print the determinant of the matrix to -100 <= m[i][j] <= 100

My solution, code, problem, question so far:

**SOLUTION**

Create an array with n empty positions, in the future those positions will store other arrays, they will be each line of the matrix.

Loop through each empty position to fill with a new matrixLine

Create a variable inside the loop that will be a  matrix line with elements

Loop the element list to get the necessary elements of a line

Put the matrix line with elements on the final matrix

**CODE**

```
    function createMatrix(rowsAndColumns, elementsList) {
        const finalMatrix = Array(rowsAndColumns)
    
        for(let i = 0; i < finalMatrix.length; i++) {
            let matrixLineWithElements = []
            for(let k = 0; k < rowsAndColumns; k++) {
                matrixLineWithElements[k] = elementsList[k]
         }
            finalMatrix[i] = matrixLineWithElements
         }
    }
```

**PROBLEM**

As you have probably noticed on the code, I'm taking the same elements from the list to form a line. The final matrix is formed successfully, but I can't figure out how to cout different values per line, here's an image of my terminal:

[image: 4x4 matrix]

**QUESTIONS**

I stopped trying to figure out while code and took the following notes -

If I have a list of four elements:

```
[10. 90, 100, 25]
```

I will form a matrix 2X2, so I need to count the elements of the list.

[image: 4 elements list = 2X2 matrix]

0(zero) and 2   are the start point of the counting, with a counting salt of 2 (same value of n variable).

There's some kind of pattern here, look, if I got a 9 element list, such as

```
[10, 90, 100, 25, 36, 48, 2, 5, 6]
```

I will form a matrix 3X3, so I need to count the elements of the list.

[image: 9 elements list = 3X3 matrix]

0(zero), 3 and 6 are the starting point of counting, with a counting salt of 3 (same value of n variable).

How can I do this counting programmatically?

Do my approach and thinking on the problem make some sense or there are better ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go by examples

|  | Col 0 | Col 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Row 0** | 0 | 1 |
| **Row 1** | 2 | 3 |

|  | Col 0 | Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Row 0** | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| **Row 1** | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| **Row 2** | 6 | 7 | 8 |

These are 2 "matrices" with cells that I filled with indexes of `elementsList` elements that are to be placed in them.

You can see that for the "0th" row the column number is the index, but for the 1st row it's the column index increased by the number of elements in the first row.
In the 2nd row it's the column index increased by 2 times the length of row (or by the number of elements already placed if we go with the second version of code - with counter).

We can deduce that nth row indexes start at n*(length of row) and increase by one just as the column indexes hence the formula for the `elementsList` index in the matrix cell: `(row number) * (length of row) + columnn index`

```js
function createMatrix(rowsAndColumns, elementsList) {
  const finalMatrix = Array(rowsAndColumns)

  for(let i = 0; i < finalMatrix.length; i++) {
      let matrixLineWithElements = []
      for(let k = 0; k < rowsAndColumns; k++) {
          matrixLineWithElements[k] = elementsList[k+i*finalMatrix.length] // here you just needed to add i times (max i)
   }
      finalMatrix[i] = matrixLineWithElements
   }
   return finalMatrix // I added this only so that it can be printed
}
console.log(createMatrix(2,[1,2,3,4]))
```

Other option:

```js
function createMatrix(rowsAndColumns, elementsList) {
  const finalMatrix = Array(rowsAndColumns)
  let counter = 0 // Added counter
  for(let i = 0; i < finalMatrix.length; i++) {
      let matrixLineWithElements = []
      for(let k = 0; k < rowsAndColumns; k++) {
          matrixLineWithElements[k] = elementsList[counter] 
          counter+=1 // Increment counter
   }
      finalMatrix[i] = matrixLineWithElements
   }
   return finalMatrix // I added this only so that it can be printed
}
console.log(createMatrix(2,[1,2,3,4]))
```

However, I dislike mutating the variables

```js
function createMatrix(n, elementsList) {
      const range = (length) => [...Array(length).keys()]
      const finalMatrix = range(n).map((i) =>
        range(n).map((j) =>
          elementsList[i * n + j]
      ))
       return finalMatrix // I added this only so that it can be printed
    }
    console.log(createMatrix(2,[1,2,3,4]))
```

Comment: Thank you @Vulwsztyn. 
Now I'm gonna study every way of doing that, on the first, can you explain  how to you get to - k+i*finalMatrix.length. 
I mean, I know you're summing the indexes and multiplying by the final matrix length, but how you know it could work, how do you thought it?

Comment: I've done it so many times it comes naturally, but I'll try to explain, by editing the answer.

Comment: Great explanation, straight to the point I couldn't understand. Thanks again.